# How to enable optional foreign key with cascade delete?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities named `User` and `Department`.

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string? DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department? Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<User>? Users { get; set; }
}
```

### Desired behavior

- User and department have a one-to-many relationship. A user can have a department and a department can have multiple users.
- Both sides of the relation are optional. A user could have no department and a department could have no users.
- When a department is deleted, all related users are deleted as well.

How can I achieve this behavior using EFCore?

### My attempt

I have the following code in my `AppDbContext.cs`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Department)
        .WithMany(e => e.Users)
        .IsRequired(false) // The result is same with or without this line
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

However, when I set the department of a user null and save it, it just gets deleted with no exception or feedback.

```
public async Task QuitDepartment(string userId)
{
    var user = await _db.FindAsync<User>(userId);
    user.DepartmentId = null;
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync(); // The user gets deleted here.
}
```

### Edit

As far as I understand this was not happening in older EFCore versions and got introduced later. There has been a discussion around this and some people claim that this is a regression, including myself.

For more information, refer to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27174).

And lastly, this is the workaround I have come up with:

```
public async Task QuitDepartment(string userId)
{
    var user = await _db.FindAsync<User>(userId);
    user.DepartmentId = null; // The entity state becomes "Deleted"
    _db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; // Set it back to "Modified"
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: maybe because the property is nullable?

Comment: I don't understand your comment @Jazb . Because the property is nullable, what?

Comment: the defined property `Department` is `?` on the class `User`

Comment: I still don't understand what you are saying @Jazb . Make a full sentence, please. Are you saying that making the optional foreign key's navigation property (`Department`) non-nullable, will result in the user not being deleted while quitting the department?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70667608/setting-foreign-key-to-null-is-triggering-cascade-delete-in-entity-framework-cor#comment124944008_70667608. Needs answer/resolution from EF Core team (their GitHub issue tracker) since it sounds like EFC 6.0 regression/bug.

Comment: Here is the tracking issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27174 you can watch. I've added link to your question.